# datatables.net ajax outside angular scope does not call the interceptor

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

Angular CLI: 7.3.3 | Node: 10.7.0 | OS: linux x64 | Angular: 7.2.6

I need **server side** pagination, sorting and filtering, my table will get 100.000 records easily.

Project example -> https://github.com/sibelly/angular-with-datatablesnet

This example consumes themoviedb API, it's just for testing, that is not my real scenario. Here in this project, I don't activate the server side option as I said is just for testing the calling to my interceptor, just to prove that with ajax directly the interceptor isn't called.

On my real scenario, I have a Laravel API, which has the methods that expect the pagination, sorting and filtering params, because I need it to be done server side to reach a better performance and usability.

When I call the API endpoint using HttpClient, it calls my error.interceptor.ts normally, but the pagination, sorting and filtering information isn't passing to the URL.

So, I concluded that I need to call it via Ajax when I call using the ajax the params are sent as expected.

But what happens is that the user token expire and I need to redirect to the login page again. And this is done using the interceptors of angular, that is not activated when calling using ajax directly because it is outside angular's scope.

To resume, how can I intercept my ajax calling from datatables.net framework in my angular project?
Or is there another way to make the **server side** pagination, sorting and filtering?

**movie.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() { 

//When calling this method the error.interceptor is activated normally
//this.getMostPopularMovies();   

//But when I call direct using the AJAX, the interceptor doesn't work
 this.dtOptions = {
   ajax: {
     url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=2ed54a614803785fce2d7fe401cc3b21',
     params: {
       api_key: this.moviedbService.apiKey
     },
     dataSrc: 'results'
     //type: 'GET',
     //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'))["token"]}
   },
   columns: [
     { data: 'title' },
     { data: 'release_date' }
   ]
 };
}

getMostPopularMovies(){

 this.moviedbService.getMostPopularMovies().
   subscribe((movies: any) => {
     this.moviesList = movies.results;

     console.log("====", movies);   
   }, (error: any) => {
     console.error("Erro-> ", error);
 });
}
```

Thanks, guys o/